# Weird Build Error: Facebook Swift SDK not building with Carthage in Blank project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook-ios-sdk, carthage

- Brand new ios project
- NOTHING in the folder besides an empty view controller with base setup
- `touch Cartfile`
- added `github "facebook/Facebook-SDK-Swift"` to Cartfile
- Ran `carthage bootstrap --platform iOS --cache-builds`
- Got the following error message:

---

```
*** Checking out Bolts-ObjC at "1.9.0"
*** Checking out Facebook-SDK-Swift at "0.4.0"
*** Checking out facebook-objc-sdk at "sdk-version-4.36.0"
*** No cache found for Bolts-ObjC, building with all downstream dependencies
*** xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/0p/lqn6hy6s1d9389yjr_1b8jnw0000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.RN4jiZ.log
*** Building scheme "Bolts-iOS" in Bolts.xcodeproj
*** Building scheme "Bolts-iOS-Dynamic" in Bolts.xcodeproj
*** Building scheme "FBSDKCoreKit-Dynamic" in FacebookSDK.xcworkspace
*** Building scheme "FBSDKCoreKit-Universal" in FacebookSDK.xcworkspace
Build Failed
Task failed with exit code 65:
/usr/bin/xcrun xcodebuild -workspace /Users/keitzer/src/test/Test/Carthage/Checkouts/facebook-objc-sdk/FacebookSDK.xcworkspace -scheme FBSDKCoreKit-Universal -configuration Release -derivedDataPath /Users/keitzer/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/10.0_10A255/facebook-objc-sdk/sdk-version-4.36.0 -sdk iphoneos ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= CARTHAGE=YES archive -archivePath /var/folders/0p/lqn6hy6s1d9389yjr_1b8jnw0000gn/T/facebook-objc-sdk SKIP_INSTALL=YES GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS=NO CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE=NO STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT=NO (launched in /Users/keitzer/src/test/Test/Carthage/Checkouts/facebook-objc-sdk)

This usually indicates that project itself failed to compile. Please check the xcodebuild log for more details: /var/folders/0p/lqn6hy6s1d9389yjr_1b8jnw0000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.RN4jiZ.log
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

---

- Carthage Version: 0.31.1
- Xcode 10, App Store version
- macOS 10.14 Mojave

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was SwiftLint (v. 0.29.3) preventing the Facebook Swift SDK from building. 
It was installed in my system via Brew.

**Removing SwiftLint** as a temporary solution helped.

P.S.
To uninstall all versions of SwiftLint run this command in the Terminal:

`brew uninstall --force swiftlint`